# Angularfire2 read data once

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Whenever the user is logging in, I run this to save his data in my `users` node. Unlucky, whenever the user logs out I get this error:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: permission_denied at /users/userID: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
    at Error (native)
    at G (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:75367:36)
    at Object.G (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:75371:86)
    at yh (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:75356:98)
    at nh.h.wd (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:75349:310)
    at af.wd (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:75252:364)
    at vd.hg (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:75250:280)
    at yd (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:75203:464)
    at WebSocket.La.onmessage (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:75202:245)
    at WebSocket.wrapFn [as _onmessage] (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:94097:29)
```

which means Firebase keep listening to my user until the page is redirected. so I need try run it only once. any ideas?

In the user panel, I have this code:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.authService.loadUser().subscribe(() => {
            this.user = this.authService.userData;
        });
  }
```

Which refers to my `loadUser()` method to get the data from firebase (I just tried to place take(1) but I still get this permission error):

```
loadUser() {
      return this.af.database.object('/users/'+this.uid).take(1).map(user => {
            this.userData = user;
        });
  }
```

In my logout I simply do this:

```
logout() {
      this.auth.logout();
      this.userData = null;
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }
```

I think the error occurs because firebase is keeping the connection to my user even after `this.auth.logout();` and until the router is navigating, he keeps trying to refresh the data. That's why I need to perform this action only once.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before too. It was because there were inklings of data sync calls that are happening **right after** a log out. My solution was to disconnect from firebase during the log out routine with `goOffline()`, and it will prevent any further data sync via websockets **right then**.

```
logout () {
  firebase.database().goOffline();
  // other log out code
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** If you call `goOffline()` in your logout, you **MUST** call `goOnline()` if you plan on logging in again. I would recommend just calling `goOnline()` every time you login.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same problem. I am relatively new to Observables, so I apologize if my explanation is not enterly correct.

I think the problem is you subscribed to the `FirebaseObjectObservable` returned by AngularFire's `object()` function, so even if you logout, the data is still trying to keep in sync.

My solution would be to unsubscribe before logging out, so your `logout` function would look like this:

```
logout() {
    this.loadUser().unsubscribe();
    this.auth.logout();
    this.userData = null;
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
    this.router.navigate(['']);
}
```

Hope that still helps!